# «Но» может быть общим второстепенным членом?

Tags: запятые, члены-предложения

«Мужчина предупреждал нас об опасности, но он говорил загадками(,) и нам оставалось лишь строить предположения».
«Но он говорил загадками» и «но нам оставалось лишь строить предположения», по сути.
Как правильно?

Comment: Мне ближе И в значении "поэтому": *поэтому нам оставалось,* а не *но и также.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отвечаю пока только на вопрос, вынесенный в заголовок.
Нет. Союз вообще не является членом предложения, этим он и отличается от союзного слова.
Поэтому и ни общим ни второстепенным членом быть не может.

Что касается самой фразы и пунктуации в ней, то тут возникают вопросы в отношении «но нам оставалось лишь строить предположения». Здесь очень странная для русского слуха трактовка. Не может в данном случае "И" в исходной фразе быть заменено на "но", ибо эта часть не противопоставляется предыдущей: "Мужчина предупреждал нас об опасности, но нам оставалось лишь строить предположения" - смысл теряется.

С другой стороны, есть понимание, чего хочет добиться автор, опуская эту запятую, два последних предложения, соединенные союзом И воспринимаются как однородные и отстоящие по смысловой структуре от первого предложения. Но каким образом это отсутствие запятой можно было бы обосновать с точки зрения правил, пока не очень понимаю.